# Buck Converter - Calculating Line and Load Regulation

Tags: ltspice, buck

I have a buck converter with a PWM circuit and Control Circuit in LTSpice.
I'm wondering, how do I simulate values for load regulation and line regulation?

I was thinking for line regulation I could sweep the input voltage?
But for load regulation, all I can think of is having a switch with an extra resistor that turns on and changes the output resistance.

Comment: Usually that plus the step response you described by the switch (or stepped source or load). It depends on how deep you want to go.

Comment: You can add a current source at the load and sweep that while keeping everything else constant.

Comment: @Michael And then how would I calculate the % value for load regulation. Do I have to take the time taken to sweep into account?

Comment: You sweep the current source to see the effects of different loads on the output voltage. A small current means a lighter (big resistor) load. LTSpice lets you do current sweeps, so there will be no time taken, it's a DC measurement. The % value would be from the changes in output voltage vs current